# Align Grid Columns evenly in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following ListView -

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView RowHeight="100"  Margin="0,10,2,10">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Margin="0,4,4,4" Padding="0,4,4,4">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="testLogo" HeightRequest="45" WidthRequest="45"/>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" >
                                        <Label Text="test" Font="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

This is displaying a columned grid as expected however I cannot float the `Button` elements to the very right of their respective column.

So currently the display does not look neat in that the buttons position seems to be determined by the string length of the `Label` elements.

I tried adding `VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"` to the `Buttons"`s however this had no effect.

How can I position the buttons neatly to the far right of their respective columns?

Comment: a screenshot would help to illustrate the issue you're having.  And what is the point of the two outer StackLayouts surrounding the Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use **[Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns)** as root layout , you can set the width of each Grid item proportionally.

As follow:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: i will attempt this shortly and mark correct if it works